# Mogoose validation error when writing a test with nested objectes

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mocha.js, superagent

I am writing a small application that uses javascript, node, mongoDB, and mongoose. I have two collections; users and groups where every group contains an array of users

User:{_id:{type: String, required: true} FirstName: {type: String, required: true}, ..}

Group{_id:{type: String, required: true}, users:[{user: userSchema}] }

I am writing an api unit test using Mocha and Superagent. When I insert a sample document for the group that includes a nested objects for the users, I got a validation error?

Could you please let me know what is going wrong with this example?

```
var userSchema = 
{
    _id: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    profile: {
        firstName: {
            type: String, 
            required: true
        },
        lastName: {
            type: String, 
            required: true
        }
}; 

var GroupSchema = 
{
    _id: {
        type: String, 
        required: true
    },
     users:[{
         user: User.userSchema
     }]
};
it('can query group by id', function(done) {
  var users = [
    { _id: 'az', profile: {firstName: 'a', lastName: 'z'}},
    { _id: 'bz', profile: {firstName: 'b', lastName: 'z'}},
  ];

  User.create(users, function(error, users) {
    assert.ifError(error);
    Group.create({ _id: 'ab', users: [{ _id: 'az', profile: {firstName: 'a', lastName: 'z'}}, { _id: 'bz', profile: {firstName: 'b', lastName: 'z'}}] }, function(error, doc) {
    assert.ifError(error);
    var url = URL_ROOT + '/api/groups/id/ab';

    superagent.get(url, function(error, res) {
      assert.ifError(error);
      var result;
      assert.doesNotThrow(function() {
        result = JSON.parse(res.text);
      });
      assert.ok(result.group);
      assert.equal(result.group._id, 'ab');
      done();
    });
  });
  });
});
```

Error Message:

```
 Uncaught ValidationError: ChatGroup validation failed: users.1._id: Cast to ObjectID failed for value "bz" at path "_id", users.0._id: Cast to ObjectID failed for value "az" at path "_id", users.0.user.profile.lastName: Path `user.profile.lastName` is required., users.0.user.profile.firstName: Path `user.profile.firstName` is required., users.0.user._id: Path `user._id` is required., users.1.user.profile.lastName: Path `user.profile.lastName` is required., users.1.user.profile.firstName: Path `user.profile.firstName` is
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your `GroupSchema` definition is incorrect:

```
var GroupSchema = 
{
    _id: {
        type: String, 
        required: true
    },
     users:[{
         user: User.userSchema
     }]
};
```

The way you're using it in the test `users` array should have type of `User.userSchema` array:

```
var GroupSchema = 
{
    _id: {
        type: String, 
        required: true
    },
     users:[{
         type: User.userSchema // type, not 'user'
     }]
     // OR just: users: [User.userSchema]
};
```

Otherwise, if you still need to use your original schema, then in your test you should use it this way:

```
  var users = [
    { user: { _id: 'az', profile: {firstName: 'a', lastName: 'z'}} },
    { user: { _id: 'bz', profile: {firstName: 'b', lastName: 'z'}} },
  ];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this change worked fine. "OR just: users: [User.userSchema]".